# Seforim about Halachic status of Beta Israel

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, ethiopian-beta-israel

I am looking for any seforim that talk about the halachic status of the Beta Israel (Ethiopian Jews).

(I remember once seeing a book generally about yichus of Jews, mainly the Russians and the Ethiopians - it was yellow and had pictures of olga dolls on the front cover - if someone answers with the name of that book, that is most preferable)

Comment: R. Ovadiah Yosef wrote a famous responsa (YO vol. 8 EH 11) regarding the admittance and “Returnee Law” vis a vis the Falashas. However, his approach was based mostly on earlier poskim and does not investigate the actual history of them. Hagai Ehrlich has written a lot on the Ethiopian Jews. (There was a thorough essay in the journal ‘Assufot’ many years ago on this topic but can’t recall the name; perhaps it was Ehrlich too.) Of the plentiful research done, recently R./Dr. (?) Sharon Shalom authore ‘Mi’Sinai Le’Ethiopia’ tracing Beta Israel’s lineage... *cont*.

Comment: ...and attempting to synthesize the group’s various “traditions” within the rubric of traditional *halachah*.